# How to find the Scroll Bar width for ScrollerView in Silverlight

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, scrollbar

Basically I need to know the `ScrollViewer` ScrollBar **width**.

This answer [How to find Vertical Scrollbar width of a Scrollviewer in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701760/how-to-find-vertical-scrollbar-width-of-a-scrollviewer-in-c-sharp)

doesn't work

```
SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidth
```

Any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution here [Changing the width of a vertical scrollbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10685833/changing-the-width-of-a-vertical-scrollbar/10695901#comment45905245_10695901)

```
ScrollBar vertical = ((FrameworkElement)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(scrollviewer1, 0)).FindName("VerticalScrollBar") as ScrollBar;

var w = vertical.Width;
```